# Python 2.7 (SharpDevelop 4.4) Re: adding assemblies using CLR .Net

Tags: python, python-2.7, clr, ironpython, sharpdevelop

I need to find a solution to a Python problem. My code is included in the
pictures for SharpDevelop 4.4. As you can see in one of the pictures (the Python
console), it recognizes the `clr.AddReference()` function. I am using
`Newtonsoft.Json.dll` for .Net 4. It gives an error (when run from being
compiled) `System.IO.IOException`.

I tried to remove spaces in the folders and it still gives the same error (see
picture). Does anyone know if I am missing something such as a configuration
property? (Note: I am using this as a test case for loading in C# assemblies.) I
will need to load several in eventually. Adding references into the project does
not seem to work.

[Project Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4coc.png)

[Python Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzhKD.png)

[Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VxV5.png)

[Removed Spaces in folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDZwi.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution based on other posts:

1. I removed the spaces in the path (not sure if this affects it)
2. I unblocked the dll (mentioned in another post)
3. I called clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(r"C:\filedir\file.dll")
   I confused this step before (with ToFile). This includes the
   full path (mentioned in another post)
4. I am not sure if my file is a 32 or 64 bit dll (mentioned in another
   post) I have it set to anycpu. The reference mentioned a 32 app must
   ref a 32 bit dll and the same for 64 bit.